# Preventing Duplicate ID Creation in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

In my Node/MongoDB backend I have a model that references a payers collection, like so:

```
clients: [{ id: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'clients' } }],
```

This is working, in that an id that's a reference to the correct "client" gets inserted. However, what's also happening is that mongo is auto-inserting a mongo ID. So in the document in question I end up with this:

```
clients: [{
    id: 6b8702ad021ba27d4a3b26h9, // my correct ref object ID
    _id: 4n8702bv036ba12g6a3b28f4 // an additional object ID auto inserted by mongo
}]
```

How do I prevent the auto insertion of the mongo ID in a situation like this? And, relatedly, if I were to use an `_` in my original ref, like so:

```
clients: [{ _id: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'clients' } }],
```

...would this prevent this from happening to begin with, since there would already be a value for "_id"? In other words, would Mongo then NOT auto insert another ID? If so, that's the route I will take.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, overwriting _id will work. Just be aware that _id is your database's primary key, so it needs to be unique or Mongo will throw an error.